view names of all tables in my database or oracle cli
if we write code in oracle sql command line like
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM user_tables;  (it will give us the total number of tables in database).
if we write
SELECT table_name  FROM user_tables;  ( it is displaying all the names of table).
But the problem is it also display the name of table which i didn't created, means the tables which are generated by system and i don't want to display tables that are system generated. I only wants to display the tables name which i had been created.

What have you tried?  Have you tried googling it?  It is pretty simple if you do.  First link I found gave me this:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153436/i-want-to-see-all-tables-of-db-but-no-system-tables

user_tables shows tables owned by the current user.  What system-generated table names are you seeing?  It is possible that you have incorrectly logged in to the database as a system-provided user (generally 'sys' or 'system') and have created tables there.  That is not supported.  You need to create a new user that will own whatever tables you want to create and create those tables in that new schema.  Or you have created that user but then run a script that creates system tables in that schema.  Which, again, would be incorrect.

SELECT table_name 
FROM all_tables 
WHERE owner = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' 
AND table_name NOT IN 
( 'systable1', 'systable2' ) 
ORDER BY table_name;

it shows you all user created tables in a specific schema and exclude system tables
